# How to unistal an app that was installed during debug

Tags: android

How to uninstall an app that was installed during debug in samsung j7 prime ?
when i tried get his error

[Package installer keeps stopping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxgln.jpg)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxgln.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Open your device's settings app. ...

1. Scroll down and tap Apps. It's in the "Device" section.
2. Scroll down and tap the app you want to deleted.
3. Tap UNINSTALL. If there is no UNINSTALL button
4. Tap OK to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

you can check the package name using the command:

```
adb shell 'pm list packages -f'
```